# VSCode Status Bar Half Hidden Below Taskbar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm on a monitor with 2560x1440 resolution, and when I maximize my VSCode instance the borders seem to go beyond the screen resolution, like this:

[image]

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: close vscode, Unlock your windows task bar, increase decrease once and lock it back. Then try opening VSCode

Comment: Nope... didn't help :-(